# Tidying up - recoding new variable using case_when doesn't like my operators

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been experimenting with a Kaggle dataset.  I have this code here, which I'd like to make tidy:

```
nbhdprice <- summarize(group_by(train, Neighborhood),
          mean(SalePrice, na.rm=T))

nbhdprice_lo <- filter(nbhdprice, nbhdprice$`mean(SalePrice, na.rm = T)` < 140000)
nbhdprice_med <- filter(nbhdprice, nbhdprice$`mean(SalePrice, na.rm = T)` < 200000 &
                          nbhdprice$`mean(SalePrice, na.rm = T)` >= 140000 )
nbhdprice_hi <- filter(nbhdprice, nbhdprice$`mean(SalePrice, na.rm = T)` >= 200000)

train$nbhd_price_level[train$Neighborhood %in% nbhdprice_lo$Neighborhood] <- 1
train$nbhd_price_level[train$Neighborhood %in% nbhdprice_med$Neighborhood] <- 2
train$nbhd_price_level[train$Neighborhood %in% nbhdprice_hi$Neighborhood] <- 3
```

I can't quite figure out how to do it.  I have tried this (and a variety of other things), to no avail:

```
train %>%
  group_by(Neighborhood) %>%
  mutate(mean_nbhd_price = mean(SalePrice, na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(nbhd_price_level = case_when(mean_nbhd_price %in% <140000 ~ 1,
                                      mean_nbhd_price %in% < 200000 && >= 140000 ~ 2,
                                      mean_nbhd_price %in% >= 200000 ~ 3))
```

Can I even use the %in% operator this way? And why does case_when (or mutate or whatever is wrong) hate my comparison operators (<, >=) so much?

Comment: Can you show us what your data looks like using ``dput()`` and be more explicit about what your output need to look like. Thanks.

Comment: Your use of operators seems to be a bit different.  Please check `%in% <140000`.  Perhaps, you meant `mean_nbhd_price < 140000 ~1` and in the next line, it may be `between(mean_nbhd_price, 20000, 14000) ~2`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, akrun is correct.  I was using %in% in a dumb (and useless) way.  Removing that and use of between solves the problem.

```
train %>%
  group_by(Neighborhood) %>%
  mutate(mean_nbhd_price = mean(SalePrice, na.rm = T)) %>%
  mutate(nbhd_price_level = case_when(mean_nbhd_price < 140000 ~ 1,
                                      between(mean_nbhd_price, 140000, 200000) ~ 2,
                                      mean_nbhd_price >= 200000 ~ 3))
```

No `%in%` required when you're already referring to the variable (doh!) and `between` solved the problem of operator complaints.